# Regular expression for extract line between two characters

Tags: bash, sed

I have several sequences to test to see if they are present in my file and I want to extract them in another file. The sequences start with a unique id that must be kept and end with ">" that I don't want to keep. I did a test but I have a problem with the regular expression

```
    #!/bin/bash


cat data.fsa | grep "Qrob" | wc -l

for gene_id in 'gene1' 'gene2' 
do
   if cat "data.fsa" |grep $gene_id >/dev/null 2>&1
then 
       echo "data.fsa" | sed -n "s/.*${gene_id}\(.*\)>.*/\"\1\"/p" 
else 
        continue
fi
done
```

How do I do this? Thanks for your help

Comment: please also include sample input (few lines from Qrob_H2.3_Genes_v2.2_20161004.CDS_nuc.fsa e.g) and expected output

Comment: try this: `"s/.*${gene_id}\(.*\)\>.*/\"\1\"/p"` i.e. try escpaing the `>` after `(.*)` - `\>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand my error thanks to you ! Thank you.

```
sed -n "/^>$gene_id/,/^>/p" data.fsa >> test.fsa && sed -i '$d' test.fsa
```

I generate the file directly and I delete with `sed -i '$d' test.fsa` manually the last selection.